# Weird MIPS assembler behavior with jump (and link) instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, disassembly, binutils

So, we're studying MIPS architecture at school and we're implementing a MIPS32 architecture. I thought I'd use GNU cross-binutils as assembler but I'm getting weird output when dealing with instructions jal, j and jr. The assembler seems to insert the instructions at the wrong places. I have no idea why this happens, and I doubt the MIPS assembler would be that broken, so I assume this is supposed to happen.

Here is my dummy assembly file:

```
.section .text
.globl __start

__start:
   addi $a0, $0, 100
   addi $a1, $0, 200 
   jal test

test:
   add $v0, $a0, $a1
   jr $ra
```

However, when I disassemble I get this output:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__start>:
   0:   20040064    addi    a0,zero,100
   4:   0c000003    jal c <test>    <--- Why is jal coming before addi?
   8:   200500c8    addi    a1,zero,200

0000000c <test>:
   c:   03e00008    jr  ra  <--- Why is jr coming before add?
  10:   00851020    add v0,a0,a1
    ...
```

Is this some architectural quirk? If so, what is the rationale behind this?

EDIT:
Tested adding some nop's just for the heck ...

```
.section .text
.globl __start

__start:
   addi $a0, $0, 100
   addi $a1, $0, 200 
   nop
   jal test

test:
   add $v0, $a0, $a1
   nop
   jr $ra
```

and it gives me something that seems somewhat correct.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__start>:
   0:   20040064    addi    a0,zero,100
   4:   200500c8    addi    a1,zero,200
   8:   0c000004    jal 10 <test>
   c:   00000000    nop

00000010 <test>:
  10:   00851020    add v0,a0,a1
  14:   03e00008    jr  ra
  18:   00000000    nop
  1c:   00000000    nop
```

Why are jal and j swapping places with the last instruction?

Comment: Looks like an endian problem inside the compiler (or the disassembler), just on the command layer instead of the byte layer... strange...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MIPS has explicit pipeline hazards; the instruction immediately following a branch or jump instruction will always be executed (this instruction is sometimes referred to as the "branch delay slot").  If your code was really assembled exactly as you wrote it:

```
__start:
   addi $a0, $0, 100
   addi $a1, $0, 200 
   jal test

test:
   add $v0, $a0, $a1
   jr $ra
```

then the `add` instruction would be executed twice around the time that the `jal` happens: once in the delay slot, and once on the following cycle when the program counter change has actually taken effect.

By default, the GNU assembler reorders instructions for you: it is clear that the second `addi` must always be executed, so it can be swapped with the `jal` instruction, so that the `addi` moves into the delay slot.  (In cases where the assembler can't deduce that it is safe to do this, it will insert a `nop` into the delay slot instead.)

If you don't want it to do this reordering for you, add the directive

```
.set noreorder
```

at the top of your source file.  You must deal with the hazards yourself in this case.  If you do this, I recommend annotating the delay slots so that they stand out - e.g. by adding an extra space (or two) of indentation.  For example:

```
.set noreorder

__start:
   addi $a0, $0, 100
   jal test
     addi $a1, $0, 200 

test:
   add $v0, $a0, $a1
   jr $ra
     nop
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. Our implementation is single cycle, so I'll use .set noreorder :).

Comment: As a historical note, compilers traditionally just filled the branch delay slot with a nop. I'm not sure when things have changed to "just let the assembler worry about it".

Comment: It appears that the GNU binutils toolchain actually does both. I'd love to know the circumstances that decide between whether it fills the branch delay slot with a `nop` and when it inserts the assembled instruction into the previous slot.