# How to turn off MIPS-GCC automatic instruction reordering?

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips

Following this question: [Weird MIPS assembler behavior with jump (and link) instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807480/weird-mips-assembler-behavior-with-jump-and-link-instruction) I have a working GNU assembly toolchain for my single cycle MIPS project (no branch delay slot!). I would really prefer to write in C though. The code itself generated from the compiler does run, but I have to manually edit the assembly source every time since GCC for some reason likes to automatically reorder the branching instructions itself. I don't want to hack this with a script to figure out when to reorder the branches back again.

Is there a possible way to circumvent this? GCC generates code like this for some reason:

```
.set noreorder
...
jr $ra <-- GCC reordered for me!
addi $v0, $v0, 10 <--
...
.set reorder
```

where I really want to feed the assembler something like this:

```
.set noreorder
addi $v0, $v0, 10
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to turn it off since delay slots are present in all MIPS variants. I think it's much better if you implement delay slots in your emulator. This will also make it closer to real hardware.
Barring that, you can probably patch gcc to stop trying to fill the delay slots.

Comment: It's implemented in hardware, so will be a bit messy to restructure lots of the design for that. I guess I'll have to write a small script for this, then.

Answer (score 10):

pass the `-mips1` and `-fno-delayed-branch` flags to gcc.

Comment: And then just remove the NOPs.  gcc still compiles for the real MIPS ISA, that just disables taking advantage. 
 https://godbolt.org/g/XmxVMu.  Handy if you want code for SPIM or MARS with their default of simulating a MIPS with no branch delay.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386888) / [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444)