# buildroot，how to set the host platform architecture

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, buildroot, mips64

I want to build a cross compile toolchain by buildroot, the build platform architecture is x86, the host platform architecture is mips, and the target platform architecture is mips64, so how should i configure the buildroot? I can't find configuration options related to the host architecture.

I use Buildroot 2021.05.

Comment: What do you mean by build platform, host platform and target platform? Why you have 3 platforms? Probably you mean that you have 2 targets, that need to both run Embedded Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Buildroot:

- the machine on which you build is called host. Buildroot downloads and builds host packages, in order to prepare to cross-compilation.
- machine on which you are going to run your Embedded Linux is called target.

So if your target is MIPS, you should select this as target architecture and start the build. Buildroot will be able to figure out the toolchain needed and properly build your Embedded Linux image for the target (kernel, bootloader, rootfs).

This answer may help if you are building for MIPS:
[Cross compiling for MIPS router from x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751709/cross-compiling-for-mips-router-from-x86)

You can also build a minimal image using an existing defconfig:
For example:

```
cd buildroot
make qemu_mips64r6_malta && make
```

which will create an image for QEMU with MIPS 64-bit architecture for Malta board.

I guess your confusion comes from the fact that you have 2 target CPUs that need to run Linux, and you call them host & target. But in buildroot terms, **host** is the build machine, and **target** is the embedded board/CPU. You don't need to change host/build machine architecture.