# How to cross-compile for MIPS?

Tags: c, mips, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, toolchain

I have a DVB receiver ([set-top box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-top_box)) similar like [Dreambox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreambox) and it has MIPS cpu

It has [embedded Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_Linux) and I can connect to it with [telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)

Question is how to compile simple "[Hello World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world)" application in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)? Where to get [toolchain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain), [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sdk)?

Comment: hmmm [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+cross-compile+for+MIPS) to the rescue -- [1st hit on my computer](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/HOWTO/MIPS-HOWTO-9.html)

Comment: @pmg that didn't help... there was only text without links and I couldn't get those tools...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175450/is-there-a-way-to-use-gcc-to-convert-c-to-mips)

Comment: Actually you might not need a full toolchain to do cross compile... Try `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends gcc-mips-linux-gnu cpp-mips-linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [Codescape SDK](https://www.mips.com/develop/tools/codescape-mips-sdk/).

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, thanks :) weird that I didn't find it with google...

Answer (score 6):

http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains

There you have some prebuilt cross compilers, or the instruction to build GCC as a cross compiler.