# Convert C to MIPS64 Assembly

Tags: c, gcc, mips, mips64

I have written some code in C and need to convert this to MIPS 64, with and without optimisation. I have been trying to convert this with gcc but this converts it to x86 which is far more complex. Furthermore, I have been trying to find a cross compiler but have not been able to get any compiler to work. Any help and suggestions will tremendously be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cross-compile for MIPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291190/how-to-cross-compile-for-mips)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading and installing Codesourcery codebench for MIPS, invoke the MIPS gcc cross compiler for the MIPS 64 revision 2 architecture as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSourcery\Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_MIPS_GNU_Linux\bin\mips-linux-gnu-gcc -march=mips64r2 foo.c -S
```

This generates MIPS assembly source code in `foo.s`.

The documentation that was installed with codebench will tell you the other possible values for the `-march` option.  Other gcc flags like `-S` and `-O` work as normal.

Comment: markgz thanks for your advise! I downloaded and installed Codesourcery for MIPS. When I try to run the c code with the following command the terminal does not output any information nor errors (the main issue is that it does not output a .s file). C:\Program Files\CodeSourcery\Sourcery_CodeBench_for_MIPS_GNU_Linux\bin>mips-linux-gnu-gcc -march=mips64r2 "C:\Users\Alex van Rijs\Documents\ccode.c" -S

Comment: gcc seems to have trouble with dos paths. Try cd-ing to the directory where your source code is, and running the compiler there. Also try adding the codesourcery \bin directory to your PATH.  Or simpler yet, just install Cygwin and run the tools in a cygwin window.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a MIPS cross compiler, instead of a gcc that targets x86, you can complete this "conversion" (compilation). If you need to find a MIPS cross compiler (gcc), you can get one pre-built from codesourcery.com

The wording in your question seems to suggest you don't care as much that the output is MIPS, but rather you want the output to be less complex than x86. If this is the case, you might also examine the ARM output.

Comment: I have downloaded  the software from codesourcery but I don't see an option to compile it to mips64. Furthermore, I tried to build a cross-compiler but the options don't seem to work. I can run several files like mips-unknown-linux-gnu-  but not sure which one and how to use the options, since it doesnt recognize flags as -o and -S

Comment: @AlexvanRijs Just to be clear, if you've downloaded a compiler that generates MIPS code, there are no flags to use, it already does what you want.