# Compile C into MIPS

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, mips, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a file of C code into mips assembly. My OS is suse linux and I already have gcc and cross-mips-binutils installed - I simply don't know what commands to use to cross-compile into mips.

I already used:

gcc -S text.c -o text.s

and it compiled fine - just not into mips.
I also looked through other posts here on stack overflow like: [How to cross-compile for MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291190/how-to-cross-compile-for-mips) but either they are not helpful or like this one, the helpful links don't work anymore.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Comment: Make sure you have the mips gcc cross-compiler and that you actually invoke that. Just having the binutils is not going to be enough.

Comment: If you just want to see Mips assembly produced by a C or C++ source program, you can use my online demo: http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=340 Select the target processor under "Output Options."

Answer (score 3):

`cross-mips-binutils` is not sufficient for compilation, only linking, creating archives, etc.  You need `cross-mips-gcc` in order to generate MIPS assembly.

Comment: ... and you need to actually call the proper compiler binary, i.e. not the system's default `gcc`, which is probably building for the host system.