# Can't Compile for MIPS or ATOM with gcc

Tags: gcc, instruction-set

Using the following commands, I am trying to compile to assembly, in different ISAs

```
gcc -S -march=atom -o mainAtom.s main.c
```

But This still generates a x86 assembly format.

```
gcc -S -march=mips32 -o mainMIPS.s main.c
```

But i get the following error.

> main.c:1:0: error: bad value (mips32) for -march= switch
>   void f() {
>   ^

How can I solve this?

> gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design every version of GCC can only compile code for a single target. To compile MIPS, you need to install MIPS cross-toolchain (see [How to cross-compile for MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291190/how-to-cross-compile-for-mips)).