# Prebuilt MIPS cross compiler with toolchain for MS-Windows

Tags: gcc, mips, cross-compiling, toolchain

I'm using a MIPS cross compiler on my Linux machine which works great.
Now I need to compile the same application on Windows.

I'm searching the web for some prebuilt MIPS cross compiler (with toolchain) for MS-Windows, but without success.

Since I'm not sure how to do so, I'm asking if someone knows such prebuilt toolchain? or some guide how to convert my Linux toolchain for windows if it's possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If you install cygwin or msys, building GCC from source shouldn't be too difficult. See e.g. [this guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/N64_Programming/Compiling) (you might have to change some flags depending on what your target architecture is).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cross-compile for MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291190/how-to-cross-compile-for-mips)

Comment: Hi @markgz, It's not the same, since as mentioned, I could not find prebuilt toolchain as the one I need. I already checked that case, but it did not  help me. 
The first replay here is promoting and I'm working on it. Keep updating.

Comment: Adding to [the guide from mark](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/N64_Programming/Compiling) together with  [this guide](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_a_newer_version_of_GCC) to have a better potential to build the MIPS cross compiler. Yet, although too many errors from my tries so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Codescape MIPS SDK](https://www.mips.com/develop/tools/codescape-mips-sdk/).

Comment: Great! that's what I needed. Using the tool-chain, I managed to compile my application with it, but somehow I can't execute the compiled application on the target: "File not found".. I suspect it's related to the 32b/64b differences, but keep checking it.. great helper forward! thanks!

Comment: The link is already down:(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Mentor has taken away the free MIPS toolchain from the CodeSourcery distribution.  Maybe one of these might still work: https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains.