# Translating from C to MIPS

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I need this translated into MIPS Assembly (to work on Mars Assembler)

```
void mm ( double x[][], double y[][], double z[][], int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i !=n; i++)
        for (j=0; j !=n; j++)
            z[i][j] = 0.0;
    for (k=0; k !=n; k++)
        z[i][j] = z[i][j] + x[i][k] * y[k][j];
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a compiler?

Comment: The first set of loops is trivial to implement. The second loop requires some floating point architecture knowledge. You can find help with both in this [lovely PDF](http://www.eit.lth.se/fileadmin/eit/courses/edi021/datablad/Processors/MIPS_Soft.pdf). We're going to need to see some work on your part towards solving this problem.

Comment: Would you like fries with that?

Comment: Duplicate of un-answered [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444).  Related: an answer on [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386888) covers some basics

Answer (score 5):

This seems a little bit like a "Do My Homework" question, but i'll give you a hint.

Passing the [`-S` switch to gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) will cause it to emit assembly code. Note, this code may need to be tweaked for the mars assembler.

Good luck!

Comment: Furthermore, you may be able to cross-compile using `gcc` directly into MIPS: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: Well it'll certainly not be MIPS assembly with an out of the box GCC compiler on his machine.

Comment: Sorry, i meant mips-gcc.

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67/mips1_core_samples README has instructions on how to build a gcc cross compiler.

Comment: or just use the lite edition from code sourcery (now part of mentor graphics)