# what is wrong in my MIPS32 assembly code?

Tags: c, recursion, assembly, depth-first-search, mips32

I have a C code to use DFS to search for single-source-shortest-path:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int buffer[1025], dist[32], visited[32];

void dfs_sssp(int n, int * graph);
void dfs(int n, int * graph, int u, int cur_dist);

int main()
{
    FILE * f;
    int n;

    // Input
    f = fopen("./test.dat", "rb");
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    n = buffer[0];
    int * graph = (int *)(buffer + 1);

    // DFS
    dfs_sssp(n, graph);

    // Output
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", dist[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void dfs_sssp(int n, int * graph)
{
    // Initialization
    dist[0] = 0;
    visited[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        dist[i] = -1;
        visited[i] = 0;
    }

    // Start recursion
    dfs(n, graph, 0, 0);
}

void dfs(int n, int * graph, int u, int cur_dist)
{
    // Update
    visited[u] = 1;
    if (dist[u] == -1 || dist[u] > cur_dist)
    {
        dist[u] = cur_dist;
    }

    // Traverse every unvisited neighbor
    for (int v = 0; v < n; v++)
    {
        if (visited[v] != 0) continue;
        int addr = (u << 5) + v;
        if (graph[addr] == -1) continue;
        dfs(n, graph, v, cur_dist + graph[addr]);
    }

    // Restore
    visited[u] = 0;
}
```

and I want to translate it to MIPS32,here is my inplementation:

```
.data
filename: .asciiz "test.dat"
.align 4
buffer:   .space  4100
##### You may add more code HERE if necessary #####
.align 4
dist:     .space  128
.align 4
visited:  .space  128

.text
main:
    # Open file
    la   $a0, filename  # load filename
    li   $a1, 0         # flag
    li   $a2, 0         # mode
    li   $v0, 13        # open file syscall index
    syscall

    # Read file
    move $a0, $v0       # load file description to $a0
    la   $a1, buffer    # buffer address
    li   $a2, 4100      # buffer size
    li   $v0, 14        # read file syscall index
    syscall

    # Close file
    li   $v0, 16        # close file syscall index
    syscall

    # Parameters
    la   $t0, buffer
    lw   $s0, 0($t0)    # set $s0 to n
    move $a0, $s0       # set $a0 to n
    addi $a1, $t0, 4    # set $a1 to &graph

    # Call DFS
    jal  dfs_sssp

    # Print results
    li   $t0, 1
    la   $t1, dist
    print_entry:
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    lw   $a0, 0($t1)
    li   $v0, 1         # print int syscall index
    syscall
    li   $a0, ' '
    li   $v0, 11        # print char syscall index
    syscall
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    blt  $t0, $s0, print_entry

    # Return 0
    li   $a0, 0
    li   $v0, 17
    syscall

dfs_sssp:
    sub $sp, $sp, 8         # allocate stacl space
    sw $ra, 4($sp)          # save $ra
    sw $s0, 0($sp)          # save $s0

    # Initialization
    la $s0, dist        # $s0 = &dist
    la $s1, visited     # $s1 = &visited

    addi $t0, $zero, 0          # $t0 = 0
    sw $t0, 0($s0)              # dist[0] = 0

    addi $t0, $zero, 0          # $t0 = 0
    sw $t0, 0($s1)              # visited[0] = 0

    addi $t0, $zero, 1          # $t0 = 1
    init_loop:
        sll $t1, $t0, 2       # pointer += 4
        add $t2, $s0, $t1     # $t2 = &dist[i]
        add $t3, $s1, $t1     # $t3 = &visited[i]

        addi $t4, $zero, -1     # $t4 = -1
        sw $t4, 0($t2)          # dist[i] = -1
        sw $zero, 0($t3)        # visited[i] = 0

        addi $t0, $t0, 1      # i++
        slt $t6, $t0, $a0     # $t6 = i < n
        beqz $t6, init_end    # if i >= n, break
        j init_loop

    init_end:

    move $a0, $a0       # $a0 = n       n
    move $a1, $a1       # $a1 = &graph  &graph
    move $a2, $zero     # $a2 = 0       source  u
    move $a3, $zero     # $a3 = 0       cur_dist

    jal dfs

    lw $s0, 0($sp)       # restore $s0
    lw $ra, 4($sp)       # restore $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 8      # deallocate stack space

    jr $ra

dfs:
    sub $sp, $sp, 12       # allocate stack space
    sw $ra, 8($sp)         # save $ra
    sw $a2, 4($sp)         # save $a2   source  u
    sw $a3, 0($sp)         # save $a3   cur_dist

    # Update
    sll $t0, $a2, 2        # u << 2
    add $t1, $s1, $t0      # $t1 = &visited[u]
    addi $t2, $zero, 1     # $t2 = 1
    sw $t2, 0($t1)         # visited[u] = 1

    add $t1, $s0, $t0       # $t1 = &dist[u]
    lw $t8, 0($t1)          # $t8 = dist[u]

    seq $t2, $t8, -1        # $t2 = (dist[u] == -1)
    slt $t3, $a3, $t8       # $t3 = (cur_dist < dist[u])
    or $t4, $t2, $t3        # $t4 = (dist[u] == -1) || (cur_dist < dist[u])
    beq $t4, $zero, jump

    sw $a3, 0($t1)          # dist[u] = cur_dist

    jump:

    # Recursion
    addi $s7, $zero, 0      # $s7 = 0 v= 0
    loop:
        sll $t1, $s7, 2       # v << 2
        add $t2, $s1, $t1     # $t2 = &visited[v]
        lw $t2, 0($t2)        # $t2 = visited[v]

        sne $t2, $t2, $zero   # $t2 = (visited[v] != 0)
        beq $t2, 1, continue    

        sll $t3, $a2, 5       # u << 5
        add $t3, $t3, $s7     # u << 5 + v addr

        sll $t3, $t3, 2       # addr << 2
        add $t3, $t3, $a1     # &graph[addr]
        lw $t3, 0($t3)        # graph[addr]

        seq $t4, $t3, -1      # $t4 = (graph[addr] == -1)
        beq $t4, 1, continue

        add $t5, $a3, $t3     # $t5 = cur_dist + graph[addr]
        move $a2, $s7         # $a2 = v
        move $a3, $t5         # $a3 = cur_dist + graph[addr]

        sub $sp, $sp, 4       # allocate stack space
        sw $s7, 0($sp)        # save $s7

        jal dfs

        lw $s7, 0($sp)        # restore $s7
        add $sp, $sp, 4       # deallocate stack space

        continue:
            addi $s7, $s7, 1      # i++
            slt $t6, $s7, $a0     # $t6 = i < n
            beqz $t6, loop_end    # if i >= n, break
            j loop

    loop_end:

    sll $t0, $a2, 2        # u << 2
    add $t1, $s1, $t0      # $t1 = &visited[u]
    sw $zero, 0($t1)       # visited[u] = 0

    lw $a3, 0($sp)         # restore $a3  cur_dist
    lw $a2, 4($sp)         # restore $a2  source
    lw $ra, 8($sp)         # restore $ra
    add $sp, $sp, 12       # deallocate stack space

    jr $ra
```

After that, I use Mars to test my assembly code. It could be assembled and run but the result is not correct. I guess there is something wrong when I call "dfs" recursively. Can some kind friends help me point out where is wrong and fix it?

I have tried to debug and compare the code in visual studio step-by-step but the progress just confuse me a lot.
In addition, I tried to convert the C code in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/), but there is no MIPS32 option and since I am new to assembly code, I cannot understand what the code means in godbolt:

```
visited:
dist:
        .word   -1
        .word   -1
        .word   -1
        .word   -1
        .word   -1
        .word   -1
dfs(int, int*, int, int):
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-40
        sw      $31,36($sp)
        sw      $fp,32($sp)
        move    $fp,$sp
        sw      $4,40($fp)
        sw      $5,44($fp)
        sw      $6,48($fp)
        sw      $7,52($fp)
        lui     $2,%hi(visited)
        lw      $3,48($fp)
        nop
        sll     $3,$3,2
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo(visited)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        li      $3,1                        # 0x1
        sw      $3,0($2)
        lui     $2,%hi(dist)
        lw      $3,48($fp)
        nop
        sll     $3,$3,2
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo(dist)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lw      $3,0($2)
        li      $2,-1                 # 0xffffffffffffffff
        beq     $3,$2,$L2
        nop

        lui     $2,%hi(dist)
        lw      $3,48($fp)
        nop
        sll     $3,$3,2
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo(dist)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lw      $3,0($2)
        lw      $2,52($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$2,$3
        beq     $2,$0,$L3
        nop

$L2:
        lui     $2,%hi(dist)
        lw      $3,48($fp)
        nop
        sll     $3,$3,2
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo(dist)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lw      $3,52($fp)
        nop
        sw      $3,0($2)
$L3:
        sw      $0,24($fp)
$L8:
        lw      $3,24($fp)
        lw      $2,40($fp)
        nop
        slt     $2,$3,$2
        beq     $2,$0,$L4
        nop

        lui     $2,%hi(visited)
        lw      $3,24($fp)
        nop
        sll     $3,$3,2
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo(visited)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lw      $2,0($2)
        nop
        bne     $2,$0,$L9
        nop

        lw      $2,48($fp)
        nop
        sll     $3,$2,5
        lw      $2,24($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        sw      $2,28($fp)
        lw      $2,28($fp)
        nop
        sll     $2,$2,2
        lw      $3,44($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lw      $3,0($2)
        li      $2,-1                 # 0xffffffffffffffff
        beq     $3,$2,$L10
        nop

        lw      $2,28($fp)
        nop
        sll     $2,$2,2
        lw      $3,44($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        lw      $3,0($2)
        lw      $2,52($fp)
        nop
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        move    $7,$2
        lw      $6,24($fp)
        lw      $5,44($fp)
        lw      $4,40($fp)
        jal     dfs(int, int*, int, int)
        nop

        b       $L6
        nop

$L9:
        nop
        b       $L6
        nop

$L10:
        nop
$L6:
        lw      $2,24($fp)
        nop
        addiu   $2,$2,1
        sw      $2,24($fp)
        b       $L8
        nop

$L4:
        lui     $2,%hi(visited)
        lw      $3,48($fp)
        nop
        sll     $3,$3,2
        addiu   $2,$2,%lo(visited)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        sw      $0,0($2)
        nop
        move    $sp,$fp
        lw      $31,36($sp)
        lw      $fp,32($sp)
        addiu   $sp,$sp,40
        j       $31
        nop
```

Comment: Godbolt has MIPS GCC.  MIPS32 is a later revision of MIPS, not a new architecture; you can use `-march=mips32` if you really want that instead of classic `-march=mips1` with load delay slots or whatever the default is.  See also [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386888) / [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444)

Comment: It looks like you did find the MIPS option on Godbolt.  See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Register_File for mapping those numeric register "names" to ABI names like `$v0`.  You're compiling as C++, with name demangling for the disassembly, hence the fake symbol names like `dfs(int, int*, int, int):` instead of just `dfs:`.  Also, directives are filtered by default on Godbolt, so you don't see the `.section .data` or `.text`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/55q8fPvv3

Comment: Does the C code work?  If so, then compare the assembly execution with the C to see where it differs.  If not then debug the C code!