# C/C++ to MIPS Assembly

Tags: gcc, compilation, mips

I know that to compile to assembly, I should use the `-S`option with `gcc` or `g++`, but how do I get MIPS assembly?

I tried

```
g++ -march=mips2 dll.c
```

but that gives the error

```
dll.c:1:0: error: bad value (mips2) for -march= switch
```

I saw a suggestion of the compile command `mips_gcc`, but I can't find how to install that compiler.

I'm using Ubuntu 64-bit, if that helps.

Comment: Related, for people looking for MARS / SPIM (rather than Linux MIPS or other real OSes), see [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444) and [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386888)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a version of gcc that is built as a MIPS [cross compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).  You can download the free Mentor/Codesourcery MIPS gnu/gcc cross compilation tool chain from [here](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/). This toolchain is available for both Windows and Linux.

After downloading, installing and adding the tool chain to your path you would say:

```
mips-linux-gnu-g++ -march=mips32r2 -S dll.c
```

to compile your code to MIPS32R2 assembly.

UPDATE 8/2017:
It looks like Sourcery CodeBench free cross compiler for MIPS is no longer available at Mentor's site. 
Try the free toolchain at [Imagination's site](https://community.imgtec.com/developers/mips/tools/codescape-mips-sdk/).

Comment: Thanks! I'm downloading it right now, I'll put up a comment once I've used it :)

Comment: Does it require 8 gigs of memory??

Comment: @asymptotically: in my experience it uses about as much memory as normal gcc. It worked just fine on a Ubuntu running in a VM with only 1GB of memory.

Comment: The site only claims: "Sourcery CodeBench Lite Edition includes:

    GNU C and C++ compilers
    GNU assembler and linker
    C and C++ runtime libraries
    GNU debugger
"

Comment: Updated with a link to Imagination's toolchain.

Comment: The link https://community.imgtec.com/developers/mips/tools/codescape-mips-sdk/ seems not to work any more.