# How to convert C++ program to Mips assembly language in MARS

Tags: mips

A C++ program to be converted to mips assembly language

```
#include<iostream>

  using namespace std;
       void redressement(int tab1[], int tab2[], int N){

       int i=0
       while(i<N){
       if(tab1[i]<0) tab2[i]=0;
       else tab2[i]=tab1[i];
       i++;
         }
         }
       void affiche(int tab[], int N){
       int i = 0 ;
       for(i=0; i<N ; i++) cout<<tab[i]<< " ";
       }

      int main(void)
     {
      int tab1[6] = { 20, 40, -6, 90, 2, 10 };
      int tab2[6];
      redressement(tab1,tab2,6);
      affiche(tab2,6);

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a cross compiler for mips? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982857/c-c-to-mips-assembly

Comment: i'm using MARS, i need the code asap , PLEASE !!!

Comment: There is no easy way using MARS. As it sais "MIPS Assembler and Runtime Simulator". It does not support C++. You need a crosscompiler.

Comment: Your question can currently be summarized as _"Can you do my homework for me?"_, which isn't suitable for StackOverflow. You need to make an effort at solving this yourself. If you run into a more specific problem that you can formulate into a question, then ask about that.

Comment: Some more tips on what options to use for the GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Options.html

Comment: First step, convert the program to the equivalent C program. This will get you closer to something you can convert to assembly.

Comment: Duplicate of un-answered [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444).  Related: an answer on [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386888)