# gcc command for converting c code to MIPS assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, mips

I was studying about MIPS assembly Language.
I heard that there is a gcc command for converting c source code to MIPS Assembly code.

Comment: simple google searching led me here - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Options.html  ... but I don't understand how you plan to study MIPS with this.

Comment: `I was studying about MIPS assembly Language.` Typically assembly generated by compilers are for assembler to read not for human. I don't think this is a good way to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `gcc -S file.c`, gcc will convert the C code to assembly.

You'll need to be running on a MIPS system, or have a MIPS cross-compiler, for this to work! In other words, plain out-of-the-box GCC on an x86 system **cannot do this** because it is set up only to build x86 code.

Here are some resources for getting MIPS cross-compilers set up on various Linux OSs: http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains

(BTW, MIPS code is highly optimizable, so you should play around with the `-O` flags to see the effects of different kinds of optimizations.)

There are many other threads on setting up MIPS cross-compilers, e.g. [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4175450/20789)