# Converting a C program to MIPS

Tags: c, mips

I have to convert the following C function to MIPS:

```
int my_function(int x, int y)
{
 int i,a;
 a = x+y;
 i = x-2;
 a = a+i;
 return a;
}
```

> Assume that the variables x and y are passed from argument registers $a0 and $a1 respectively. The returned value should be stored in register $v0. Note that you need to use stack to store any other registers if you use them in this procedure.

Since I am new to MIPS I tried referring to a [C to MIPS online convertor](https://godbolt.org/) and I got this result:

```
my_function(int, int):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add     eax, edx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
    sub     eax, 2
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Can I get a better solution for this?

Comment: Please define *better solution*. and what have you tried?

Comment: @Raptor : i have no idea about the solution sir, i tried online compiling link, but i guess its incorrect.
That's why i wanted a better solution

Comment: @S Ringne: This all rather depends on the specific operating environment from which you intend to call the compiled function, in particular whether it is 32 or 64-bit MIPS and the calling convention used. Compilation of a single function in isolation is a rather peculair thing to do so I think you could shed much of light on the question by describing more specifically what you need to code for and how it is to be integrated into the system.

Comment: [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386888) shows how to enable optimization and still get meaningful output, with gcc `-O3 -march=mips32r2 -Wall -fverbose-asm -fno-delayed-branch`.  Or `-Og` might be useful for minimal optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you're generating code for x86-64 - you need to [select a MIPS compiler from the popup menu above the assembly pane](https://godbolt.org/g/at5iPU):

[image]

After you've done that you'll probably see generated code like this:

```
$LFB0 = .
my_function(int, int):
$LVL0 = .
        addu    $2,$4,$5
$LVL1 = .
        addiu   $4,$4,-2
$LVL2 = .
        j       $31
        addu    $2,$4,$2
```

Note that the compiler has optimised away some of the redundant operations in the original C code. If you want to see an unoptimised version then [specify `-O0` in the compiler options](https://godbolt.org/g/Tz6d17) and you'll see something much less efficient, but closer to the original source:

```
$LFB0 = .
my_function(int, int):
        addiu   $sp,$sp,-16
        sw      $fp,12($sp)
        move    $fp,$sp
        sw      $4,16($fp)
        sw      $5,20($fp)
        lw      $3,16($fp)
        lw      $2,20($fp)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        sw      $2,0($fp)
        lw      $2,16($fp)
        addiu   $2,$2,-2
        sw      $2,4($fp)
        lw      $3,0($fp)
        lw      $2,4($fp)
        addu    $2,$3,$2
        sw      $2,0($fp)
        lw      $2,0($fp)
        move    $sp,$fp
        lw      $fp,12($sp)
        addiu   $sp,$sp,16
        j       $31
        nop
```

Comment: Assume that the variables x and y are passed from argument registers $a0 and $a 1 respectively. The returned value should be stored in register $v0. Note that you need to use stack to store any other registers if you use them in this procedure.

Comment: This was the overall requirement of my question

Comment: @SRingne: sure - obviously you'll need to take care of the calling convention and other minor details in the assignment - using godbolt to generate the guts of the function is just a useful helping hand...