# copy a set of continuous values from one location to another in MIPS assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, memory, mips

I am trying to achieve the following via MIPS assembly:

```
for(int i=0; i<n ; ++i){
   arr2[i] = arr1[i];
}
```

- `$t2` stores the address of starting point of `arr1` and `$t3` stores the starting point of `arr2`
- `$t1` stores the value `n` upto which the loop runs.

My assembly code is as follows:

```
#save the value of $t2 and $t3
move $t8, $t2
move $t9, $t3

#init i=0
move $s7, $zero

copyArrayLoop:  beq $s7, $t1, endCopyLoop
        sw $t2, 0($t3)
        addi $t2, $t2, 4
        addi $t3, $t3, 4
        addi $s7, $s7, 1  
        j copyArrayLoop

endCopyLoop: move $t2, $t8
         move $t3, $t9
```

however, this copies the address of values stored at `$t2` as it increments, and not the value in memory at address denoted by `$t2`, can anyone point what's going wrong here?

Comment: Just like you need `sw` to write to `arr2`, you need `lw` to read from `arr1`.

Comment: [Converting a C program to MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42921824) shows how to use a compiler to see what instructions it would use.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I was missing this crucial thing!