# C program for MIPS74kc never returns

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mips

I have a simple C "Hello world" program, compiled using GCC toolchain for mips74-kc running a Linux S/O (kernel 3.10.36)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The program is compiled on a x64-86 Ubuntu machine, as I don't have GCC available on the MIPS machine. I compile the program with the static linking flag.

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc --verbose -static -march=74kc main.c -o main
```

When I launch the program on the MIPS processor, the program holds and never returns, consuming 100 % of the CPU.

Does anyone have a clue on why this could happen?

Comment: Its not exactly a duplicate, but look at this question and in particular the first answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175450/is-there-a-way-to-use-gcc-to-convert-c-to-mips

Comment: @tom : That is not what he is saying.  he is running a cross-compiler on Ubuntu on an x86 development host.  He does not have a native compiler running on the embedded target - this is normal - to use cross-development for embedded targets.

Comment: All you need is to have GDBServer running on the embedded target, then you can debug remotely running GDB from the development host.  I would not go much further with embedded Linux development until you have an debugging solution - then you can answer your own question.

Comment: @Clifford - oh,,, ok, then yes I was pretty naive about it --- thanks for the correction - that comment is deleted, but is the other one relevant with the link?

Comment: I cannot install gdbserver on the embedded target as it is not connected to internet. Are there already compiled gdbserver? I would compile it myself but I would probably compile it wrong.