# Can you pass code from c ++ to assembly language in MARS sofware?

Tags: assembly, mars-simulator

[cod in c++,  what it does is put the reverse side of a text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJd58.jpg)

Comment: assembly language  in mars software

Comment: I recently posted an answer on [Is there a way to use gcc to convert C to MIPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386888) specifically about using compiler output with MARS.  Of course you can't call standard library functions like `ostream::operator<<`, you have to use MARS toy system calls.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler translates that code to assembly language for you.

try to view the generated assembly:

```
gcc -S filename.cpp
```