# Hello, is there anyway to avoid using the %hi and %lo when translating C-Code into MIPS, all my function that are addiu are making errors

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Here is some of my Code:

```
    la     $t2, $LC1
    la      $t9,($t2)
    addiu   $t3,$t2,%lo($LC1)
    lw      $t8,4($t3)
    addiu   $t3,$t2,%lo($LC1)
    lw      $t7,8($t3)
    addiu   $t3,$t2,%lo($LC1)
    lw      $t6,12($t3)
    addiu   $t3,$t2,%lo($LC1)
    lw      $t5,16($t3)
    addiu   $t3,$t2,%lo($LC1)
    lw      $t4,20($t3)
    addiu   $t3,$t2,%lo($LC1)
```

Here are the errors:

```
Error in /Applications/mips7.asm line 101 column 9: "addiu": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: addiu $t1,$t2,-100
Error in /Applications/mips7.asm line 103 column 9: "addiu": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: addiu $t1,$t2,-100
Error in /Applications/mips7.asm line 105 column 9: "addiu": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: addiu $t1,$t2,-100
Error in /Applications/mips7.asm line 107 column 9: "addiu": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: addiu $t1,$t2,-100
Error in /Applications/mips7.asm line 109 column 9: "addiu": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: addiu $t1,$t2,-100
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175450/is-there-a-way-to-use-gcc-to-convert-c-to-mips/63386888#63386888

Answer (score 1):

MIPS compilers, assemblers and linkers use multiple instruction and `%hi` with `lui` and `%lo` with `addiu`.

MARS does not support the `%hi` or `%lo` address manipulation functions — instead it offers a pseudo instruction `la` that loads the whole 32-bit address of the label into the register.  (This instruction expands into two machine code instructions that involve `lui` and another like `ori`.)

So, collapse the two instructions using `%hi` & `%lo` into one `la` for MARS, and then use that address to accomplish the intended effect: load an address, or load or store to global data label.

If the intended effect is to load or store from a global/static data label, MARS also supports `lw $t0, label`, and `sw $t0, label` pseudo instruction forms.

Generally speaking, MARS pseudo instructions hide underlying machine code details, including hiding opportunities for manual optimization when one of the `lui` instructions could have been eliminated or shared.  If we do `global_var++` for example, that should require only one `lui`, one `lw` and one `sw` but in MARS `lw $, label` followed by `sw $, label` will involve two `lui` instructions.

---

The following doesn't make sense for MARS:

```
la     $t2, $LC1
addiu   $t3,$t2,%lo($LC1)
```

Because the `la` has already produced the full 32-bit address for `$LC1`, there's no point in adding an offset `%lo($LC1)` to that pointer.

Comment: Ok so, that means I do not have to use the addiu function at all, because  the la function for the full 32 bit address accounts for it already?

Comment: And also each time there is an addiu function with the %lo($LC1)or %hi($LC1) what should I put instead??                           Here is an example within the code I already provided:                                                                                 
    lw      $t8,4($t3)
    addiu   $t3,$t2,%lo($LC1)

Comment: The idea is to understand that `%hi` and `%lo` are used together to form a 32-bit address that is used to either: make the address into a register, load a value from data label, or store a value to data label.  Then to do the equivalent to one of those in MARS, which is an `la` to make the address into a register, or, something like `lw` or `sw` to a label.